# DuckDB deleting rows from dataframe error: RuntimeError: Binder Error: Can only delete from base table

Tags: python, pandas, duckdb

I have just started using DuckDB in python jupyter notebook.  So far everything has worked great.  I can't figure out how to delete records from a dataframe.  When I try:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"i":[1, 2, 3, 4], "j":["one", "two", "three", "four"]})

con = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:')

con.execute('delete FROM test_df where i=4')
```

this generates:

```
RuntimeError: Binder Error: Can only delete from base table!
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong.  I am just beginning to use python and pandas and really like the SQL features of duckdb operating on a dataframe

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

DuckDB does not alter dataframes.
However, You can generate a new dataframe without the tuples you can delete.

e.g.,

```py
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"i":[1, 2, 3, 4], "j":["one", "two", "three", "four"]})

con = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:')

test_df = con.execute('select * from test_df where i!=4').df()
```